# Consider all the permutations of the word "ENDEANOEL"

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all the permutations of the word "ENDEANOEL" :

1)*What is the number of permutations containing the word "ENDEA" ?* 
I can't understand how to approach this problem!!

2)*Number of permutations in which letter E occurs in the first and last position ?*
 Ok I tried this: Out of nine letters i placed two E's at the edges.Out of the remaining two similar N's and 5 different letters present.So probably it is 7!/2!

3)*The number of permutations in which none of the letters D,L,N  do not occur in the last 5 positions.* This I got as 4!/2!*5!/3!

4)*The number of permutations in which letters A,E,O occurs only in odd positions?*
This I got as $4!/2! * 5!/3!$

So can someone please help me with the first question? Hints will suffice!And are the other results correct?

Comment: 2nd looks correct to me

Comment: Luckily I found a solution here !! :-P https://books.google.co.in/books?id=0oAULosCnuAC&pg=SL3-PA66&lpg=SL3-PA66&dq=Number+of+permutations+in+which+letter+E+occurs+in+the+first+and+last+position+?&source=bl&ots=SxACOmycWa&sig=pGs06YB6fv842EGCID7SPxkISoE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SlwyVYKJMcWouwTN4YFA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Number%20of%20permutations%20in%20which%20letter%20E%20occurs%20in%20the%20first%20and%20last%20position%20%3F&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers and their explanations are as follows:

1) E,N,D,E,A have been used so the alphabets left are N,O,E,L now they can be placed before or after the instance of ENDEA,

So the cases are ____ENDEA, ***ENDEA*, __ENDEA**,_ENDEA___,ENDEA___ each case has 4! permutations so the answer is (after taking ENDEA as one alphabet X) WE need arrangements of X,N,O,E,L so its $$5!$$

2) You are correct on this the answer is $$\frac{7!}{2!}$$

3) You are correct on this too since there are 9 alphabets and 4 of them can't be used for the final 5 places it can be said that $$\frac{4!}{2!} and \frac{5!}{3!}=\frac{4!*5!}{2!*3!} $$

4) You are correct on this too since there are only 5 odd places and 5 alphabets to place in the and the even places needs to be filled with the rest 4 it can be said that $$\frac{4!}{2!} and \frac{5!}{3!}=\frac{4!*5!}{2!*3!} $$

So you were right on all those you answered. Remember for future that when something needs to be a subset(a part of) something place things before and after it by making cases.

Comment: thnx i had to write 5*4!=5! but i wrote 4*4! so it was my mistake